# How to process null TransactionReceipt?

Tags: raw-transaction, error, nonce, documentation

I have some transaction that is sent and from time to time when I call the **eth_getTransactionReceipt** I get a null.

I see esentially two approaches for handling this:

- I could reiterate the call to **eth_getTransactionReceipt** in order to eventually get a non null TransactionReceipt. This approach works in some cases but will not handle the case where the transaction fails.
- Resending the exact same transaction with **eth_sendRawTransaction** results in a "nonce too low" in the case where the transaction is still pending.

How could one handle those two possible scenarios (transaction not yet implemented, or transaction did not pass)?

I have two questions on the error codes:

- I saw in some cases the "known transaction" as error instead of "nonce too low". Indeed if a transaction is resent then one would expect to get a different error than in cases of nonce too low.
- By the way what could be the list of possible error codes? Standard references such as https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC do not give the list of possible errors.

Is there a recommended way to handle error cases of transactions?